how could I resolve Value error between my input and output while running the fit function?
Here is the shape of my data
print(X_train1_padded.shape, y_train1_padded.shape)
print(X_val1_padded.shape, y_val1_padded.shape)
print(X_test1_padded.shape, y_test1_padded.shape)

(203161, 496, 1) (203161, 496, 1)
(118096, 496, 1) (118096, 496, 1)
(85491, 496, 1) (85491, 496, 1)

And here is my model code
# Initialize the Sequential model
model = Sequential()

# 1D Convolutional Layer 1
model.add(Conv1D(8, 4, activation="linear", input_shape=(sequence_len, 1), padding="same", strides=1))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))

# 1D Convolutional Layer 2
model.add(Conv1D(8, 4, activation="linear", padding="same", strides=1))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))

model.add(Flatten())

# Fully Connected Layers
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense((sequence_len - 3) * 8, activation='relu'))  # Adjusted input size

model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))

model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense((sequence_len - 3) * 8, activation='relu'))  # Adjusted input size

model.add(Dropout(0.2))

# UpSampling1D Layer 1
model.add(Reshape(((sequence_len-3), 8)))
model.add(UpSampling1D(size=2))
model.add(Conv1D(1, 4, activation="linear", padding="same", strides=1))

# UpSampling1D Layer 2
model.add(UpSampling1D(size=2))
# Adjust the number of filters and kernel size to match the required output shape
model.add(Conv1D(1, 4, activation="linear", padding="same", strides=1))

model.summary()
optimizer = SGD(lr=0.01, momentum=0.9, decay=1e-6)
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=optimizer)

I am trying to run it but the main issue is that the input and output shape is not matched. Here is the error
model.fit(X_train1_padded, y_train1_padded, epochs=50, batch_size=16, validation_data=(X_val1_padded, y_val1_padded),shuffle=True)


 ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 1972 and 496 for '{{node mean_squared_error/SquaredDifference}} = SquaredDifference[T=DT_FLOAT](sequential_11/conv1d_37/BiasAdd, IteratorGetNext:1)' with input shapes: [?,1972,1], [?,496,1].

I can't change the model because its the requirement, so could anyone suggest something to do with the shape of the data?

maybe first use print(), print(len(...)) to see what you have in variables in this line. Maybe they are different than you expect.

I tried it but they are same

but error message shows that some values in line model.fit(...) have wrong size. So you have to check size (or .shape) for X_train1_padded, y_train1_padded, X_val1_padded, y_val1_padded. OR maybe your model expect data with different sizes. what values is in input_shape=(sequence_len, 1) ?

for the X (234, 2304, 1)
and for Y (234, 2304, 1)
I have appended 0's in both to have the same size but still I am following error
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 9204 and 2304 for '{{node mean_absolute_error/sub}} = Sub[T=DT_FLOAT](sequential_6/conv1d_27/BiasAdd, IteratorGetNext:1)' with input shapes: [?,9204,1], [?,2304,1].

maybe one of your layer makes problem - but I don't know how to test it. Normally I would suggest to remove some elements, or start with empty network and add layer after layer - to see if it works - but with layers it would problem to create new Y for this.

maybe you could ask on similar portal DataScience or CrossValidated - maybe they will have better experience.

I have reviewed your code and made some changes,updated input_shape to match
sequence_length and updated dense layers input size to match flattened output
size these changes made the code to work.Please refer to this gist and let me
know if you are still facing the issues
